# How to disable Bootstraps button checkbox hover and focus effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstraps button checkboxes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="0"> SomeText1 </label>
      <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1"> SomeText2 </label>
    </div>
```

But I am struggeling with disabling the hover and focus effect. I want to do this becuase with the hover and focus effect you can't tell the current status of the button/checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/r2m1vzxo/1/

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why don't you remove the `btn-outline-secondary` property from the `label`?

Comment: Because thats the style I would like the buttons to have. When removed I am loosing the check/not checked functionality. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zfq0njrm/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my understanding is correct is this what you need?

```css
label.btn.btn-outline-secondary {
  color: #6c757d;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

label.btn.btn-outline-secondary.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>



  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="0"> SomeText1 </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary active">
        <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="1"> SomeText2 </label>
  </div>



  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Close, thanks for pointing in the right direction! This is what I was looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/v3c8o719/

Comment: Glad that I was able to give you 2cents, cheers! I will update the answer for future purpose :)